# AngularJS - jasmine test cases for user defned lodash functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, lodash

I have created an application in angularjs and lodash, the application is working fine, Also i have also learned writing test cases for angular js, Now the problem is that i have created my own lodash methods which i am using in angular controller, can anyone please tell me how to write test cases for the user defined lodash method, my code is as given below

```
var app = angular.module('lodash', []); 
app.run(function () { 
    _.mixin({  
        getJsonObject: function () {
            var obj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                obj[arguments[i]] = arguments[++i];
            }
            return obj;
        },
        getJsonArray: function () {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                arr.push(arguments[i]);
            }
            return arr;
        } 
    }); 
});
```

**[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V6NjrFSNZN7zslcD6P4a?p=preview)**

Comment: just make test case to check if you are passing argument to both functon does it return what you expect

Comment: actually i have many other user defined function in lo-dash apart from that, so i need to write separate testcases for those, and not through the controller

Comment: yes you have to separately that the purpose of unit test cases...

Comment: i am not getting you....can you show me an example

Comment: I think you should take these functions out of angular run blocks. that way you can run tests easily without loading modules.

Comment: What you earn by putting lodash into an angular module if not that you injecting anything?

Comment: if i am not injecting `lodash` in `app` module then i wont be able to access those user defined lodash methods

Comment: @IlanFrumer can you please give me some solution for this